# Restore M2 products after migration

Tags: product, magento2.3.0, magento-1.9.2.1, data-migration-tool

I used [data-migration-tool](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool.html) and did migration from 1.9 to 2.3 but lost all the products which were already in M2.

Before the migration there were around 2000 products and now they lost. I have backup of complete M2-database before migration.

How to get those product back in magento2.

***Update:***

I followed answer of @Mitro and it worked with some efforts but images are still not displaying though images can be open by media-url.

I tried command `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize`  but didnt work

Comment: using migration tool or any custom module ?

Comment: with data-migration-tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Connect the database before migration to magento 2.
2. Export Product from Mageneto 2 backend. Go to System -> Data Transfer -> Export
3. Save the exported product csv file.
4. Connect the migrated database to the M2
5. Go to System > Data Transfer > Import : from here you can import your old product which you have exported earlier.

Please write comment if this solution works for you. 
Thanks

Comment: I am also thinking same but I am not sure why are those products get deleted. Did you face such issue before. Migration is long process and in my case, it takes 2 hours to migrate all data because of m1 big database.

Comment: Yes I used to apply the same process and it was work for me

Comment: You don't need to do migration again. You just have to connect with those 2 databases one after other

Comment: Great. I will try and update you back.

Comment: I have done the same but images are not displaying on product-listing and product page. Here is reference link of other question https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/290347/29175 .Please check if you can help me out

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [Magento Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-preconditions.html) page.

It is clearly said that they do not recommend creating new entities (products, categories, attributes, etc.) in your Magento 2 store before migration because the Data Migration Tool overwrites such new entities with the old ones from Magento 1.

So, you need to do first import export of the products and then you need to do that migration.

Comment: All is done. Only product-images are not displaying.

Comment: Just in case anyone else has the same problem, removing the .htaccess in the media folder did the trick. I don't know if that's the best possible solution though! Thanks!

Comment: Issue is solved or not?

Comment: not solved yet !!

Comment: Still image issue there? Did you try resize command?

Comment: Yes. That's already tried

Comment: Ok sir. If possible give me development server details to try.

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on the image problem.

1. Take a product, write it's product id and check if there are images associated
2. Launch the following sql query

> SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity as
>   A, catalog_product_entity_media_gallery as B WHERE A.value_id =
>   B.value_id AND A.entity_id = [YOURPRODUCTID]

Check your tables name and insert the correct product_id.

3. Check if there are imges for that product AND if there are disabled (field disabled = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run image resize command for product image not showing?

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Answer (score 0):

Data-migration-tool tools often delete previous data like product and categories in Magento 2.So better download the CSV first and after migration of product upload the CSV from admin.Hope it will help